# Capitalization in alert text field [only first word]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a checklist app. If the user wants to add a new point on his checklist, he can push the "Add" button and an alert will appear with a UITextField to put his new task in.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

let textf = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

        if(textf.text != "")
        {
            checklist.append(textf.text!.capitalized)
        }
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Doing it like this will capitalize the words after hitting "Add". But I want that only the first word to be capitalized. Also, I want it to be on the keyboard when it appears so that the first word is capitalized right away. How can I do that?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new task", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (alertInputTextField) in

    }
```

Comment: Set the capitalization property on the textfield before you add it to the alert

Comment: @Scriptable where though?

Comment: Show the code for how to get a textfield on the alert

Comment: @Scriptable updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `autocapitalizationType` property of the textfield and set it to sentences when you add it...

```
alert.addTextField { textField in
    textField.text = "Some default text"
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .sentences 
}
```

Always refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield), it explains this quite well.

If you need to do this to a String directly just uppercase the first letter of the String.

Comment: If this fixes your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer to show the issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below function:-

```
public mutating func capitalizeFirst() {
    guard self.count > 0 else { return }
    self.replaceSubrange(startIndex...startIndex, with: String(self[startIndex]).capitalized)
}
```

or

```
public func capitalizedFirst() -> String {
    guard self.count > 0 else { return self }
    var result = self

    result.replaceSubrange(startIndex...startIndex, with: String(self[startIndex]).capitalized)
    return result
}
```

Comment: or just set `textField.autocapitalizationType = .sentences` on the textfield?

Comment: yes, i have just suggested an alternative. You can have a common structure for whole project and have these function inside that.